# I am trying to store output from calculator and display on label or text box in visual basic asp.net

Tags: asp.net, arrays

Create two buttons

- store data - The store data will store the results into array
- display data - The display data will display the contents of the array (use 10 for the array size)

`btnStore` is not storing array and `btnDisplay` is not displaying array on Label.

So far the code works on visual basic as an application. However, when I use it to build an asp.net page it is telling me 'items' is not member of 'Label'

```
Dim ara(9) As String
    Protected Sub btnStore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStore.Click
        '--StoresArray--
        If txtResult.Text <> "" Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To 9
                If ara(i) = "" Then
                    ara(i) = txtResult.Text
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next

            MsgBox("You can only store 10 results" & txtResult.Text)
            'lblDisplay.Text.(ara) 
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can't just simply dump an array into a label and expect it to be visible. The computer has no idea how you want it to be presented. You'll have to loop through the array and build a string which looks the way you want it, abd that can then be given to the label

Comment: P.s. btnDisplay isn't mentioned in your code so it's hard to see what that remark refers to. My comment above is talking about the last line before your End If statement, which you've commented out for now...but it's the only indication we have so far about how you are displaying this on screen.

Comment: As for saying the array isn't populated...given the potential problems with displaying it, how do you know this? Have you stepped through the code with the debugger? If so, then you could follow the paths taken by the code and what the values of the variables are. Without seeing your input data we can't ever be 100% sure what it will do

Comment: There's also no code shown which would cause the error you're describing. Did you forget to include some? The compiler will tell you which line is the problem